# How to append new line in an existing file?

Tags: java, file, newline, printstream

How am I supposed to append a new line after I finish adding what I am supposed to.
I have the following code:

```
        try{
            String textToAppend = question+userInput+","+typeOfAnswer;
            Files.write(Paths.get("save.txt"), textToAppend.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFileException e){

        }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
```

> **Example: question: By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known? userInput: RED typeOfAnswer will be wrong: wrong**

I get my question and real answer from a file, then I compare the real answer with the userInput and see whether the typeOfAnswer si wrong/right. I want to output the question, userInput and typeOfAnswer in a File but I have multiple questions, hence I want to output the final results each on a new line.

Comment: What exception you get?

Comment: `textToAppend += System.lineSeparator();`

Comment: @EmreSavcı I'm not getting any exceptions but if I try let's say to create the textToAppend like this: `textToAppend = "\n"+question+userInput+","+typeOfAnswer` I won't get the new information in a new line.

Comment: @Andreas tried..i have the same problem..i get sth like this: `By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?RED,wrongWhich number president was Franklin Roosevelt?RED,wrong`. There is no separation between wrong and Which

Comment: @Ryk Are you on Windows, using Notepad to show file content? If so, then be aware that Notepad doesn't recognize `\n` as an end-of-line marker. Only `\r\n`.

Comment: @GBlodgett That's not my problem tho' :)...it is not a duplication. Read again.

Comment: @Andreas I use windows

Comment: What your variables question, userInput and typeOfAnswer contains?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because simply adding `System.lineSeparator()` at the of text before writing it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented:

> ```
> textToAppend += System.lineSeparator();
> ```

*Proof*

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        save("By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?", "RED", "wrong");
        save("Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?", "RED", "wrong");
    }
    public static void save(String question, String userInput, String typeOfAnswer) throws Exception {
        String textToAppend = question + userInput + "," + typeOfAnswer;
        textToAppend += System.lineSeparator();
        Files.write(Paths.get("save.txt"), textToAppend.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    }
}
```

*File Content*

```
By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?RED,wrong
Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?RED,wrong
```

*File Content after running program 3 times*

```
By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?RED,wrong
Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?RED,wrong
By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?RED,wrong
Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?RED,wrong
By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?RED,wrong
Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?RED,wrong
```

Comment: What if my file already exists? Do I have to put StandardOpenOption.Create?

Comment: `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` means that it will create the file *if* it doesn't exist.